# celery add to broker without publishing

Tags: celery

I would like to add a message to a broker without the broker publishing it to subscribers.

I then want to, at a later date, tell the broker to publish the message.

I want to do this so I can set a one-off predefined task that can only be executed by calling it.

An alternative I have tried that doesnt work is to do:

```
task = tasks.send_message.apply_async(['hello'], countdown=60)
revoke(task.task_id, terminate=True)`
```

But this doesn't revoke the task - the task executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the RabbitMQ [dead-letter exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) extension. When you publish the task you put it on a queue with no consumers and declare the consumer queue as the dead letter queue. When the message TTL expires on the original exchange it will be dead letter to the consumer queue where it will then be consumed.

To accomplish this with Celery you would declare a queue

```
from kombu import Exchange, Queue

DEAD_LETTER_OPTIONS = {
    'x-message-ttl': 60 * 10 * 1000, # 10 mins
    'x-dead-letter-exchange': 'default',
    'x-expires': (60 * 10 + 1) * 1000,
}


CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),
    Queue('wait',  Exchange('wait', arguments=DEAD_LETTER_OPTIONS ), routing_key='wait'),
)
```

Then you would call your task and put it on the `wait` queue.

```
tasks.send_message.apply_async(['hello'], queue='wait')
```

You can also see this example of a general dead letter based countdown https://gist.github.com/dgouldin/3485236

Comment: Are the options `x-message-ttl` and `x-expires` compulsory? As per rabbitmq doc it happens when `x-message-ttl` expires or if `basic-reject` is simulated. I'm rejecting the message from celery using the same above conf. The message is appearing in `wait` queue but does not appear in `default` queue after reject. Is there some thing that I'm missing?